# Bar button item background color

Tags: swift

Can I change the background color, NOT **tint**, of the bottom bar button?

I have 3 buttons in the bottom bar and I want make orange color whole the middle button with the white image on it(1/3 of the bottom bar).

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

How can I do it? Everywhere in Google about tint, but I do not want tint, I want to change background

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html). You are right, there isn't any `backgroundColor` related methods.

But the trick is you can use the `setBackgroundImage(_:forState:barMetrics:)` method with a plain orange image.